# Why root does not source .bash_profile?

Tags: osx, root, bashrc, su

Every time I try to login as root using `su` (not `su -`), it doesn't source `.bash_profile` in user1's home directory.

Basically, my `/var/root` directory doesn't have `.bash_profile`, so I put a copy of `.bash_profile` in `/var/root` to test `su -`.

It doesn't automatically source `.bash_profile` (in `var/root`), either.

Anyway, I want to make `.bash_profile`, of user1, sourced in root account automatically when I use `su`.

What should I do?

(It worked before! One day, it just doesn't source! Maybe something changed settings in bash? It works when I enter `source .bash_profile` after login.)

I am using Mac and OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 11):

The default shell for `root` on OS X is `/bin/sh`. Its `sh` is also a version of `bash`, but [when invoked with the name `sh` Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoked-with-name-sh):

> tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of `sh` as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.
>
> When invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first attempts to **read and execute commands from `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`, in that order. ... a shell invoked as sh does not attempt to read and execute commands from any other startup files**

That is, it doesn't read `.bash_profile` at all, **regardless of whether it was invoked as a login shell or not**. You can use `.profile` instead, or even symlink one to the other. If you launch a login shell with `su -l`, `.profile` is loaded on startup, but `.bash_profile` will never be.

---

You can also [use `dscl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dscl.1.html) to change root's shell (noting that `/etc/passwd` is *not* used to determine the shell on OS X). You can check root's current shell with `dscl . -read /Users/root UserShell`; consult the documentation and think carefully before changing it to something else.

Another approach is simply to change your `su` invocation to force executing `bash` immediately.

Given what you've said, I'd probably recommend the symlink, but you may wish to look into the changes that Bash's [POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode) makes and decide whether you want to have them or not.

Answer (score 5):

Because it is not considered as a "login shell" (which is invoked directly from `login`, or `sshd`) but simple "interactive shell". See here for example: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

So force `su` using login option i.e. with `-l` option:

```
su -l
```

Or put your environment into `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 5):

The root user will try to execute the .bashrc file instead of the .bash_profile since you are not invoking a login shell.

From the bash manual `man bash`:

```
   ~/.bash_profile
          The personal initialization file, executed for login shells
   ~/.bashrc
          The individual per-interactive-shell startup file
```

Note the `~` where the .bashrc file needs to be in the homedirectory of the root user.

To actually answer your question, if you want the .bashrc file of user1 to be used I would suggest you make a (symbolic) link between the source .bashrc from user1 to the root user.

You can also consider to source the user1 .bashrc or even .bash_profile by adding the line `. /homedirectory/of/user1/.bash_profile` to the .bashrc file of the root user.